# How will I determine fundamental loop equations from a graph which contains 3 and 2 terminal circuit elements?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: question and details]

This is the question and details. I believe I could manage to get the graph from the given circuit. (part a)

This is the graph I drew. But I could not find part b and c, since they require fundamental loop equations and fundamental cut set equations. I can easily find them if 3 terminal element (the transistor here) does not exist.

[image: graph I drew]

I spent hours but could neither find any information on web nor figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can still do regular loops. For example: V65 + V54 + V48 + V86 = 0, where the indices refer to your nodes as marked in the picture.

So we have 1V + V54 + 0.5V - 2V = 0, V54 = 2V - 1V - 0.5V = 0.5V.

You can calculate the other element voltages across the terminal of the transistors the same way.

Comment: I found V53=-5V with your method. Does that mean T5 has a voltage value 5.5 (V34) ? If so, why?

Comment: V34 sounds correct. I'm not sure I understand your question about "why". That looks like a simple circuit analysis exercise and I don't think it's intended to represent a real world schematic.

Answer (score 1):

The voltages are just a matter of a few additions or subtractions once the 0 V point has been defined.

[image]